# Multiple GPUs and Multiple Executables

Tags: cuda

Suppose I have 4 GPUs and would like to run 50 CUDA programs in parallel. My question is: is the NVIDIA driver smart enough to run the 50 CUDA programs on the different GPUs or do I have to set the CUDA device for each program?

thank you

Comment: Which CUDA driver, exactly? There is more than one answer to this question....

Comment: I am using the nvidia driver version 331.20 on linux with cuda 5.5.

Comment: talon's answer is great, just something to add: if your CUDA programs use an NVIDIA engine, make sure workload distribution isn't already supported. If they're generic CUDA programs then talon's answer is probably the only way to go IMHO

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first point to make is that you cannot run 50 applications *in parallel* on 4 GPUs on just about any CUDA platform. If you have a Hyper-Q capable GPU, there is the possibility of up to 32 threads or MPI processes queuing work to the GPU. Otherwise there is a single command queue.

For anything other than the latest Kepler Tesla cards, CUDA driver only supports a single active context at a time. If you run more that one application on a GPU, the processes will both have contexts which just contend with one another in a "first come, first serve" basis. If one application blocks the other with a long running kernel or similar, there is no pre-emption or anything else which makes the process yield to another process. When the GPU is shared with a display manager, there is  a watchdog timer that will impose an upper limit of a few seconds before the application will get its context killed. The result is that only one context ever runs on the hardware at a time. Context switching isn't free, and there is a performance penalty to having multiple processes contending for a single device.

Furthermore, every context present on a GPU requires device memory. On the platform you are asking about, linux, there is no memory paging, so every context's resources must coexist in GPU memory. I don't believe it would be possible to have 12 non-trivial contexts running on any current GPU simultaneously - you would run out of available memory well before that number. Trying to run more applications would result in an context establishment failure.

As for the behaviour of the driver distributing multiple applications on multiple GPUs, AFAIK the linux driver doesn't do any intelligent distribution of processes amongst GPUs, except when one or more of the GPUs are in a non-default compute mode. If no device is specifically requested, the driver will always try and find the first valid, free GPU it can run a process or thread on. If a GPU is busy and marked compute exclusive (either thread or process) or marked prohibited, then the driver will skip over it when trying to find a GPU to run on. If all GPUs are exclusive and occupied or prohibited, then the application will fail with a no valid device available error.

So in summary,for everything other than Hyper-Q devices, there is no performance gain in doing what you are asking about (quite the opposite) and I would expected it to break if you tried. A much saner approach would be to use compute exclusivity in combination with a resource managing task scheduler like Torque or one of the (former) Sun Grid Engine versions, which could schedule your processes to run in an orderly fashion according to the availability of GPUs. This is how most general purpose HPC clusters deal with scheduling in multi-gpu environments.